# Is it possible to connect to secure websocket on custom port without proxying?

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, wss

I was trying to connect to websocket server that listens 8081 port this way `wss://host:8081` and had no effect because client had `pending` status instead of 101.

So than I've used `nginx` as proxy and all started to work. Now I connect to `wss://host/ws`.

Now I try to figure out was problem with port or maybe something else?